# Loop not repeating in Windows XP

Tags: c#

This loop is supposed to continue until the conditions are met:

```
while(listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
{
 if (m_AsyncWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Cancellation pending ...");
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
    }


  string[] workerResult = new string[10];

  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch.Start();

    foreach(var line in lines)
        {
         //Process - when a value returns true, it will be added to listbox1 and
         //so should break out of the while loop. Until the value returns true, 
         //the while loop will continue and so the foreach loop will repeat. 
        }
}
```

`lines` refers to a text document that is being read in the program.

The process is being done on a backgroundworker thread. I have also added a stopwatch in order to time how long it takes for a foreach loop to complete.

This works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 PC, however in my Windows XP VM, it will complete the entire loop once (i.e check each line in the text document), then begin a new while loop again (as the listbox is still empty), however it will not begin a new foreach loop and seems to just stop after 'Stopwatch.Start();'. The Windows XP VM is using .NET 4 framework.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "seems to just stop after `Stopwatch.Start()`." How did you determine this?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You're stealing [John Saunders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) "thing".  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech If only I could figure out how to do the inline-link thing! Oh well, I guess it makes it a bit more my "own".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Square brackets for the title followed by parenthesis for the link.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show us what exactly the `lines` is? Also, is all of that code inside BackgroundWorker's job? even that `while(listBox1.Items.Count == 0)`? How did you manage to have it? It should be throwing CrossThread-exception.

Also, in that inner foreach, you say you are adding lines to listbox1 - it should throw CrossThread exception too.

In WinForms and WPF it's not possible to touch UI elements from a thread different than the main UI thread, so if you are running that code inside BGW's job, you should be getting exceptions all over the place. (btw. I'm talking about the BGW's job, not events notifications like Progress or Completed! that notifications are synced back to UI thread)

Considering the crossthread-exceptions, maybe that's what is stopping your loop? Have you checked "Output Panel" for any First-Change exceptions logs? If they have been thrown, you'd always see them reported there.

Sidenote: On Windows7+ the exception policy was somewhat changed, and some unhandled exceptions are silenced by the UI framework. Hm, at least in WPF. I dont remember how's that in WinForms. However even if it's the source of the difference, I do not see how you could have it running in W7. It should throw those exceptions too and should break out of the loops immediatelly. Have you disabled the crossthread checks? If so, strange things may happen. You shouldn't have! They should be turned on and if you need to touch UI elements from backgroudn thread, you should use Invoke's to "temporarily" delegate that operations back to UI thread.

Comment: Sorry, all responses are loaded in to an array and reported to the ProgressChangedEventHandler, and from there the UI is updated. i.e 'bw.ReportProgress(0, workerResult);', where 'workerResult' is defined as 'string[] workerResult = new string[10];' - thank you very much for the speed response by the way.